# setBackgroundDrawableResource setScaleType(android)

Tags: android, xml

Хочу на layout установить задний фон картинку с помощью `getWindow()` вот так:

`getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_image);`

и мой `bg_image`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <bitmap

            android:src="@drawable/bg_shkaf" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

но картинка получается растянутой. Есть какое то свойство что то типа `CenterCrop` что б картинка нормально смотрелась?

Comment: Картинка под экран размером?

Comment: @AdamLuisSean нет, она немного меньше. Из-за этого растягивается. А как сделать что она хорошо выглядела, есть какие то свойства?

Comment: есть свойства для ImageView `android:scaleType="fitXY" android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: @AdamLuisSean спасибо за совет, но я в вопросе написал что использую `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_image);` для установки фонового изображение. В `bg_image` нельзя использовать `android:scaleType` может как то и можно но я не знаю. Ради этого я и создал этот вопрос